# BTRFS cannot mount after lossing USB connection

Tags: usb-drive, btrfs

I had a `btrfs` disk connected by USB, but briefly lost the connection (SATA connector fall off drive).  I tried to unmount the disk and remount, but it refuses.  I keep getting:

```bsh
$ mount /dev/sdf1 /mnt/backup/
mount: /mnt/backup: mount(2) system call failed: File exists.
```

Some notes.

- Before the USB connection was lost, the USB drive showed up as `/dev/sde1`.
- When the USB drive was reconnected, the USB drive showed up as `/dev/sdf1`.
- `dmesg` shows the warning `BTRFS warning (device <unknown>): duplicate device /dev/sdf1 devid 1 generation 9 scanned by systemd-udevd (2613105)`

Seems to be something is remembering the old USB connection to drive, which has been lost.  Ideas on how to fix this?  I'd like to avoid the Windows tech support solution of "just reboot," but that will likely fix the problem.  I would think there is something I can do to force `btrfs` to release the disconnect drive.